# Retrieve the Toolbox Image associated with standard WPF controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a slim'd down IDE inside my application to allow some basic customization of a UI page. My toolbox contains some standard WPF controls. I am however having a hard time getting the Icon associated with any of the default WPF controls, I assumed they would have been defined by `ToolboxBitmapAttribute` just like user controls, but I am not able to see any such attribute on the types.

The following alwayse returns null on "default" WPF types such as `Grid`, `Image`, `Border` etc...

```
    public Image Icon
    {
        get
        {
            Image controlImage = null;
            AttributeCollection attrCol =
                    TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(Type);
            ToolboxBitmapAttribute imageAttr = (ToolboxBitmapAttribute)
                attrCol[typeof(ToolboxBitmapAttribute)];
            if (imageAttr != null)
            {
                controlImage = imageAttr.GetImage(Type);
            }

            return controlImage;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think the icon is an embedded resource with a name matching the control, in the control's dll. http://blog.amastaneh.com/2013/07/toolbox-icon-for-wpf-custom-control.html?m=1

Comment: @Andy it looks like that is for user controls or derived controls and for specifying your own icon, I am looking for the default ones.